# BarMark drawing on top of Y Axis

Tags: swiftui, charts, ios16

**UPDATE:** So I found an answer for the display issue which is to use the string value for the date on the axis rather than the date value. `BarMark(x: .value("date", "\(item.todaysDate!)"), y: .value("hours slept", item.hoursSlept), width: 35)`. However, I can't get the dates on the x-axis now to show only Month Day (Oct 17). I am using the following formatter and code to display that chart:

```
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd"
            return formatter
        }()

var dateInitial = (item.todaysDate!, formatter: dateFormatter)
BarMark(x: .value("date", "\(dateInitial)"), y: .value("hours slept", item.hoursSlept), width: 35)
```

I'm trying to setup and utilize the new Charts framework in iOS16 for my app but it keeps drawing my bars on top of the y axis numbers and same on the left. How do I fix this so that they draw correctly? I'm trying to show the last 5 days of data from CoreData on the charts with the Date on the X axis and the value on the y axis.

```
HStack {
        Chart {
              ForEach(items.prefix(5)) { item in
                   BarMark(x: .value("date", item.todaysDate!), y: .value("hours slept", item.hoursSlept), width: 35)
                       .cornerRadius(8.0)
                       .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .top, spacing: 2.0) {
                              Text("\(item.hoursSlept, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    .font(.system(size:10))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                       }
             }
        }.chartYScale(domain: 0...12)
         .frame(height: 175)
}.padding()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it all out as follows:

```
func getDate(date:Date)->String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
    let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    return stringDate
    }

 Chart {
       ForEach(items.prefix(5)) { item in
           var dateInitial = getDate(date:(item.todaysDate!))
           BarMark(x: .value("date", "\(dateInitial)"), y: .value("hours slept", item.hoursSlept), width: 35)
                   .cornerRadius(8.0)
                   .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .top, spacing: 2.0) {
                          Text("\(item.hoursSlept, specifier: "%.2f")")
                               .font(.system(size:10))
                               .foregroundColor(.white)
                               .fontWeight(.bold)
                   }
           }
           RuleMark(y: .value("Average", avgHoursSlept))
                  .foregroundStyle(.red)
                  .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .bottomTrailing, spacing: 0.0) {
                        Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", avgHoursSlept))")
                             .foregroundColor(.red)
                  }
           }  .chartYScale(domain: 0...12)
              .frame(height: 175)
```